# My Index.cshtml see css folders but another page does not see same css folders?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have to a MVC project and my `Index.cs.html` see css folders but another page does not see same css folders?

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/zabuto_calendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/js/gritter/css/jquery.gritter.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/lineicons/style.css">
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: And the question is…? What does “does not see” mean?

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  What is the URL of a "working" page and the URL of a "not working" page?  What do the `link` tags look like on those pages?

Comment: @OndrejTucny My index.cshtml page read bootstrap.css but my customer.cshtml page (html is exactly the same with index page) is not read all css.I check my source bootstrap.css is empty

Comment: @MrtDev: When you look at the browser's debugging tools, what are the URLs being requested for the CSS files?  The one that "works" and the one that "doesn't work"?

Comment: @David That's right.There are actually two same page.Index.cshtml and Customer.cshtml.This pages html content exactly same.Two pages are in HomeController.But Index.html read all css in assets folder.But Customer.cshtml does not read this css.I check browser's source for example there is bootstrap.css but bootstrap.css folder's content is empty

Comment: @MrtDev: You're not answering the questions being asked.  We can't see your screen, you have to provide us with more details than "it works on one page but not on another".  What are the URLs of the pages when you load them in the browser, and what are the URLs of the CSS files being requested by the browser when the pages load?

Comment: @David http://localhost:9232/ is works. But http://localhost:9232/Home/Customers  is does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment:

> localhost:9232 is works. But localhost:9232/Home/Customers is does not work

That's because those URLs are going to result in requesting entirely different CSS file URLs.  Specifically, these:

- `http://localhost:9232/assets/css/bootstrap.css`
- `http://localhost:9232/Home/Customers/assets/css/bootstrap.css`

Obviously *both* of these URLs can't be correct.  In your case, only the first one is.

There are a number of approaches to take, for example you might want to look into using script bundles and style bundles in your MVC application.  That allows server-side code to determine the correct URL.  Failing that, the simplest approach would be to use absolute paths for your `link` tags instead of relative paths:

```
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Note the leading `/` on the URL.  That tells the browser to start finding that path from the root of the server, rather than from the current page.  Because when the current page is on a very different path (as yours are), the browser is going to construct very different requests for relative paths.